# PostgreSQL insert and ignore multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, upsert

I have newly created table with 4 unique fields: `nsn`, `slug`, `part_no`, `mfg_sku`.

I'm trying to insert into this table approx. 2 million rows from multiple tables, which has also repeating rows.

## so the main question is...

how to emulate `insert ignore` in this case?

Select distinct based on multiple columns or what do you suggest?

Here is the data that I want to insert to `Part` table

```
 SELECT "PartOld".id,
    "PartOld"."PartNo",
    "PartOld"."Manufacturer",
    "PartOld"."Slug",
    "PartOld"."Description",
    "PartOld"."NSN",
    NULL::numeric AS price,
    "PartOld".name,
    NULL::character varying AS mfg_sku
   FROM "PartOld"
UNION
 SELECT part_item.id,
    NULL::character varying AS "PartNo",
    part_item.manufacturer AS "Manufacturer",
    NULL::character varying AS "Slug",
    part_item.details AS "Description",
    part_item.msn AS "NSN",
    NULL::numeric AS price,
    part_item.name,
    part_item.mfg_sku
   FROM part_item_fetched part_item
```

And Here is the `Part` table.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "electronic_parts"."Part";
CREATE TABLE "electronic_parts"."Part" (
    "id" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"Part_id_seq"'::regclass),
    "part_no" varchar COLLATE "default",
    "manufacturer" varchar COLLATE "default",
    "description" text COLLATE "default",
    "slug" varchar COLLATE "default",
    "nsn" varchar COLLATE "default",
    "price" numeric,
    "name" varchar COLLATE "default",
    "mfg_sku" varchar COLLATE "default"
)
WITH (OIDS=FALSE);
ALTER TABLE "electronic_parts"."Part" OWNER TO "root";

-- ----------------------------
--  Primary key structure for table Part
-- ----------------------------
ALTER TABLE "electronic_parts"."Part" ADD PRIMARY KEY ("id") NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE;

-- ----------------------------
--  Indexes structure for table Part
-- ----------------------------
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX  "part_u1" ON "electronic_parts"."Part" USING btree(part_no COLLATE "default" "pg_catalog"."text_ops" ASC NULLS LAST);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX  "part_u2" ON "electronic_parts"."Part" USING btree(nsn COLLATE "default" "pg_catalog"."text_ops" ASC NULLS LAST);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX  "part_u3" ON "electronic_parts"."Part" USING btree(mfg_sku COLLATE "default" "pg_catalog"."text_ops" ASC NULLS LAST);
```

Comment: please specify your postgres version

Comment: @VaoTsun latest

Comment: So, apart from `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`, your input can contain duplications? Because your table's columns are unique one-by-one, neither a single `UNION`, `DISTINCT` nor even a `DISTINCT ON` will help you filter it. Is that your problem?

Comment: Here is a follow-up question: because you have 3 distinct unique columns, your input *could* look like this (only sample unique values are mentioned): `(1, 2, 10)`, `(3, 2, 11)`, `(1, 3, 12)` -- these 3 rows conflict with each other. So, you want none of them, or you want any of them (but just one, because one on its own will not conflict with itself)?

Comment: @pozs if any of them match one-by-one (say, duplicate row of nsn, duplicate of slug) then ignore

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
INSERT INTO ...
   (SELECT ...)
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

This has been available since 9.5, see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your input with [anti joins](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/16/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-postgresql/) (tipically with `NOT EXISTS()` or `LEFT JOIN + IS NULL`):

```
WITH data AS (
  -- your query here
  SELECT ...
  UNION ALL ...
),
conflicting_ids AS (
  SELECT id      FROM data GROUP BY id      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
),
conflicting_part_nos AS (
  SELECT part_no FROM data GROUP BY part_no HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
),
conflicting_nsns AS (
  SELECT nsn     FROM data GROUP BY nsn     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
),
conflicting_mfg_skus AS (
  SELECT mfg_sku FROM data GROUP BY mfg_sku HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
INSERT INTO table_name (column_names)
SELECT d.*
FROM   data d
WHERE  NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM conflicting_ids a      WHERE a.id = d.id)
AND    NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM conflicting_part_nos a WHERE a.part_no = d.part_no)
AND    NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM conflicting_nsns a     WHERE a.nsn = d.nsn)
AND    NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM conflicting_mfg_skus a WHERE a.mfg_sku = d.mfg_sku)
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
```

*Notes*: `id` is unique too, because it is the primary key. Also, because the conflicting rows are checked separately, you won't need `UNION`. You can use `UNION ALL`, which will be a slightly more efficient.

Comment: That won't insert anything because every record from `d` that you try to insert will match the same record from `a`

Comment: @Gary yeah, the condition, which should exclude the same exact row was left out. But because primary key is part of the query it will be easier to `count` unique columns first.